# direct and inverse fourier transform in EMGU CV

Tags: c#, transform, fft, emgucv, computer-vision

I'm doing a small experiment using fourier transform on emgu cv. My aim is to have the fourier transform of an image, then take the inverse fourier transform again, and check if the image shows up or not. mathematically, it should.

this is my code which i believe is correct

```
Image<Gray, float> image = new Image<Gray, float>("c://box1.png");
IntPtr complexImage = CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(image.Size, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 2);

CvInvoke.cvSetZero(complexImage);  // Initialize all elements to Zero
CvInvoke.cvSetImageCOI(complexImage, 1);
CvInvoke.cvCopy(image, complexImage, IntPtr.Zero);
CvInvoke.cvSetImageCOI(complexImage, 0);

Matrix<float> dft = new Matrix<float>(image.Rows, image.Cols, 2);
CvInvoke.cvDFT(complexImage, dft, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_DXT.CV_DXT_FORWARD, 0);


Matrix<float> idft = new Matrix<float>(dft.Rows, dft.Cols, 2);
CvInvoke.cvDFT(dft, idft, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_DXT.CV_DXT_INVERSE, 0);

IntPtr complexImage2 = CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(idft.Size, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);

CvInvoke.cvShowImage("picture", idft);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(99999); // to wait and see the picture
```

I have two problems:

1- error : an error shows up saying " OpenCV: Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels " i believe its related about the IDFT, but I couldn't solve it

2- it still shows an output image, but unfortunately, its not the original image that was input. all what show is a plain grey image.

Thanks.

Comment: Refer to this discussion here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669007/emgu-opencv-fft-of-image-not-yielding-expected-results.
The method above is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Image<Gray, System.Single> _image = new Image<Gray, System.Single>("c://box1.png");
Image<Gray, System.Single> DFTimage = new Image<Gray, System.Single>(_image.Size);
Image<Gray, System.Single> Original = new Image<Gray, System.Single>(_image.Size);
CvInvoke.cvDFT(_image.Ptr, DFTimage.Ptr,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_DXT.CV_DXT_FORWARD, -1);
CvInvoke.cvDFT(DFTimage.Ptr, Original.Ptr,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_DXT.CV_DXT_INVERSE, -1);
CvInvoke.cvShowImage("picture", Original);
```